# MSSQL select query results are in different order in node mssql driver

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, database, node-mssql

I am using [node-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) package from npm to connect my MSSQL server. My code looks like

```
const sql = require("mssql"); 
var sqlconnectionpool = new sql.ConnectionPool(...mydbconfig);

sqlconnectionpool.connect().then(pool => {
  const myquery = "select 1 ,2 as 'two',3 ,4";
  pool
    .request()
    .query(myquery)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result.recordset.toTable()));
    })
    .then(res => {
      pool.close();
    });
});
```

as a result, i was expecting

```
{
    columns: [
        { name: "", nullable: false },
        { name: "two", nullable: false },
        { name: "", nullable: false },
        { name: "", nullable: false }
    ],
    rows: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
};
```

instead i am getting

```
{
    columns: [{ name: "", nullable: false }, { name: "two", nullable: false }],
    rows: [[[1, 3, 4], 2]]
}
```

Results are automatically grouped by column names. In my case, I have column name for only one column. Since they are getting grouped by column names, the results are not in same order.

Could someone clarify how to achieve the desired result (for the above query, the numbers in same order as they are requested)?

I am using node v 8.9.4 and mssql driver 4.1.0

Comment: Give all of the columns aliases?

Comment: @TabAlleman. But in my usecase, I can't give aliases for some fields.

Comment: I am not seeing any query here, so what does this question has to do with sql-server ?

Comment: It is not query about SQL server. It is a query about handling results of the mssql nodejs drivet